# Open layer 3 find temporary layer on map (e.g. Select interaction's feature)

Tags: openlayers-3

In open layer 3, there are numerous features, like select interaction, would add  temporary layer to the map. When I working on it with my own layers, features on these temporary layer were hidden by other layers. Like the following :
[image: Marker & Pin]

When the Marker was selected, I updated the coordinates of the pin (which is on another Vector Layer). However, The selected Marker always on top of the pin, maybe I am doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the z-index of your vector layer to a higher value after moving the pin.

```
vectorLayer.setZIndex(100);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, setZIndex does not make the features in vectorLayer go on top of features in "temponary layer" of Select Interaction.